# creating lots of dimensions with crossfilter

Tags: crossfilter

Anybody have a good solution about having a lot of dimensions in crossfilter? I have a huge dataset and a lot of dimensions to handle, maybe more than 16 or even 32. I know there is the dimension.remove() function. But will this process effect the speed a lot? Pretty new to crossfilter.

Thanks,

G

Answer (score 0):

Currently the number of dimensions limited to 32. But there has been effort to lift the limit. https://github.com/square/crossfilter/pull/75